# How to loop over two python Generators

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two python generators. Say

1) `txn_gen`, yield the dictionary values like

```
{'id': 1,'ref_no': 4323453536, 'amt': 678.00, 'txn_date': '12-11-2019'}
.
.
.
{'id':10000000 , 'ref_no':8523118426, 'amt':98788.00, 'txn_date': '12-11-2019'}
```

2) acc_gen, yield the dictionary values like

```
{'ref_no': 4323453536, 'acc_no': 123456789, 'amt': 98789.00}
.
.
.
{'ref_no': 8523118426, 'acc_no': 123456789, 'amt': 45654567.00}
```

I want to loop `txn_gen` over `acc_gen` for `ref_no` matching. I am looping like this.

```
for gen1 in txn_gen:
     for gen2 in acc_gen:
          if gen1[1] == gen2[0]:
               print(gen2)
```

But I am getting only one match value ie., the first match value.  I am expecting millions of match values.

I want to improve the performance as I have millions of records.

Answer (score 1):

A generator can only be evaluated once. After you've consumed all the values in `acc_gen`, and go on to the next value in `txn_gen`, you cannot loop through `acc_gen` again.

For this kind of analysis, you can iterate through `txn_gen` and save each `ref_no` in a hash table, and then iterate through `acc_gen` to look up their `ref_no` fields.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have consumed a generator you can't iterate it again. One way is to convert them (or at least the inner one) to a list if the memory cost is acceptable:

```
acc_gen = list(acc_gen)
for gen1 in txn_gen:
   ...
```

If you cannot justify the space complexity, you must reset or re-initialise `acc_gen` before the second `for` statement.